# background-image of div not displaying properly

Tags: css, image, html, background-image

I have four divs with a background image each and one of the images is not displaying properly, but I can't figure out why

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVVSe.png

I created a jsfiddle, so you can see the whole code: http://jsfiddle.net/6bnBc/

HTML:

```
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <span>Title 2</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
nav ul li a {
    display: block; width: 120px; height: 120px;
    background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

nav ul li:nth-child(2) a {
    background-color: #58ebd3;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVVSe.png);
}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: How to fix it (question solved tho)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second image is way too big. I added `background-size: 100%;` and then it scales correct.

Answer (score 0):

I can see in your fiddle divs with images. Try putting some background-position for it, so you get that part of image, that you are looking for (or question is unclear).